# Unable to view Xcode 4.2 help “index.html” is locked for editing

Tags: xcode

When I try to search the documentation within Xcode I get the following error:

“index.html” is locked for editing and you may not be able to save your changes. Do you want to unlock it?

“index.html” is currently locked because it does not support editing.

The file “index.html” could not be unlocked.

Could not add write permission to the file because you do not own it. Try modifying the permissions of the file in the Finder or Terminal.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling without success.

Any ideas?

Comment: FYI, I had tried the various suggestions in Apple's developer site. This issue is unresolved for many as the workarounds suggested in Apple's developer site don't work for all.

Comment: -1 Exact same question: http://superuser.com/questions/348117/unable-to-view-xcode-4-2-help-index-html-is-locked-for-editing

Comment: Answer in superuser.com does not solve the problem. If you go to Apple's developers forum for iOS you will see that this issue remains *unresolved* for many users despite them trying all the suggestions posted there and here.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a solution I found on [Apple's DevForums:](https://devforums.apple.com/message/549125#549125)

> I went into Xcode preferences, went to the Downloads option, and
>   selected Documentation.  From there, I clicked 'Check and Install Now'
>   and it went and downloaded the iOS 5.0 library and 10.7 library.  Once
>   those were downloaded, help seemed to be working again via the local
>   libraries.  Hope this helps get you back on track.

And yes, I've seen the same problem that you've seen.  You just need to fully download the documentation.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work -- I did download the documentation as soon as I installed Xcode and I can see it via the browser. But the lock issue persists.

Comment: Okay.  There was a further answer on a [separate thread on devforums.apple.com](https://devforums.apple.com/message/560405#560405) (linked) -- those instructions being:
 
1) Close Xcode, go to /Developer/Documentation and delete the DocSets directory.

2) Open Xcode, go to Preferences->Downloads and click on Documentation.  Install whichever libraries you need.  It'll take a while to download as they're large.

3) Once that's done, you should be able to access your docs.  You might need to quit Xcode and restart.

Comment: This solution worked for me - so for anyone else, its worth trying even if it didn't work for Sergio. message and crash has gone.

Comment: This helped me, I have already downloaded the whole documentation in local but it seem that the remote documentation has precedence over local. So when the remote documentation is newer that local xcode open the remote one. For future i've marked the 'Check for and install updates automatically'. Xcode 4.2 on Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 2):

Update: xCode 4.2.1 fixes this problem.

Comment: Does this problem occur on earlier versions of the OS?

Answer (score 2):

I worked around the issue in Snow Leopard this way:

1. Open XCode
2. Open the organizer ( Window | Organizer )
3. Select Devices | Provisioning Profiles
4. Select my phone-provided provisioning profile and click Refresh

You do this silly thing because XCode will then display a dialog asking you to sign in with your Apple ID. If I sign in /here/ instead of on the page in the documentation, it remembers I'm signed in, shows the documentation when I ask, and doesn't crash. I have to do this every time I restart XCode, though.

YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer... Have you tried repairing permissions?

How about deleting xCode prefs?

Answer (score 0):

You can chown the documentation to your user, attempt to search, unlock the file, and then chown the documentation back.

Unfortunately, you have to search and unlock for each file individually.

```
sudo chown -R `id -un` /Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets
# Try to search; unlock the file.
sudo chown -R _devdocs /Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets
```

I don’t think it actually modifies the file — I suspect this is a problem with the new versioning feature.

Answer (score 0):

This has helped:

Become super user

% cd /Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation

% tcsh

```
foreach i ( `find . -name index.html` )
  echo $i
  xattr -d com.apple.quarantine $i
end
```

I still get the following on the first search:

Internal Error
Xcode encountered an internal logic error. Choose
"Continue" to continue running Xcode in an inconsistent
state. Choose "Crash" to halt Xcode and file a bug with 
Crash Reporter. Choosing "Crash" will result in the loss of 
all unsaved data.

[Show Details] [Continue] [Crash]

I pick [Continue] and everything works fine afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

the Better solution is Uninstall Xcode:

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools –mode=all
```

after that, install Xcod