# Xcode 4.2 search slow and locked

Tags: xcode, search

[image]

[image]

Why do I get these when trying to type in the search bar and how can i not have permissions on my own computer? mental

Answer (score 0):

Check out if this link will help you in any way

[Unable to view Xcode 4.2 help “index.html” is locked for editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044931/unable-to-view-xcode-4-2-help-index-html-is-locked-for-editing)

https://superuser.com/questions/348117/unable-to-view-xcode-4-2-help-index-html-is-locked-for-editing

**EDIT :** if you are using a beta version of xcode 4.2 this is a pretty common issue i have seen on few sites.

Just try these steps and see whether it works

1.Open Xcode menu > Preferences...
2.Click Downloads category
3.Click Documentation tab
4.Select "iOS 5.0 Library"
5.Click Check and Install Now

Hope this helps

Comment: I know that 4.3 is available for builds but not app submissions and I also noticed that 4.2.1 is available but whenever I went to install via mac app store it said installed but still only 4.2 not 4.2.1. I searched "can't upgrade 4.2 to 4.2.1 and the suggested fix was to delete the 'install xcode' from applications directory i did that and i was then able to update to 4.2.1 from app store. according to the web 4.2.1 fixes the problem with the search, as i write this its still downloading with any luck it'll be the fix.... naturally ill post the result.  Thanks Sharanya for your efforts